# Begging for upvotes in thread titles

Tags: discussion, etiquette, voting

Can we add something to the effect that "Begging for upvotes in thread titles" is not allowed to the faq?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Why only in thread titles?  The same question is of interest for vote solicitation in answers and comments.

Comment: Related: [ *Begging for Votes* ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes).

Comment: @BBischof: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/5537/revisions) is probably the instance muad is referring to.

Comment: @Kaestur Ah I see.

Answer (score 2):

That was me.  My bad.  There shouldn't have to be a rule about that.  Although since we are at meta, I'd like to suggest that perhaps there shouldn't be the rep requirement for commenting in the first place.  Presumably the idea is to keep completely random people from posting/spamming comments, but since this site is at least for the moment less populated than MO, it will take a while (longer than it should, I'd argue?) for me to be able to obtain the requisite 50 points.  As I said, I just joined this site yesterday, and I was browsing around and kept seeing things I wanted to comment on but couldn't.  That's all.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to comment on your own questions and answers to your own questions even @ rep 1.

Comment: I know.  I had comments for other questions/answers that weren't my own that didn't merit full answer-status.  It's cool to actually be able to provide worthwhile input (which I can do far more here than on MO!), and I was disappointed that I couldn't.  I had hoped that it was obvious from my question that I was hoping to be a serious and valuable contributor to the site, and that that would be sufficient justification for my rep-whoredom.  Evidently not.

Comment: @Aaron, it was clear that you are serious but if this sort of thing starts... next, people will be mistagging questions to get more 'hits' like they do on youtube and all this sort of annoying stuff.

Comment: Well Aaron, you will have to get to busting your chops here; if you say you can provide worthwhile input to a lot of questions posed here, getting up to rep 50 shouldn't be that hard for you. ;) muad is correct, let's not start a trend of rep-harlotry here.

Comment: Is that a challenge?!??  If so, I accept!  Once I finish my real work, of course.  :)

Comment: Although n.b. that I only made a relative statement, not an absolute one

Comment: +1 to G.M. for "rep-harlotry."